# problema con mandar un form que contiene informacion de un poligono dibujado con leaflet draw pero solo envia un json vacio

Tags: javascript, django, formularios, leaflet

[image: en la imagen se ve que al inspeccionar la pagina la solictud json esta vacio]

```
//este coidigo extrae informacion de un poligono dibujado en leaflet drawn y lo convierte a cadena para enviar en json pero el json en la solicitud esta vacio 

        document.getElementById('zona-form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

//aca el objeto se convierte a geojson para luego convertiser a un cadea string json

var geojson = drawnItems.toGeoJSON();
            var polygon = JSON.stringify(geojson.geometry);

            fetch('/guardar_zona/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
               
                    poligono: polygon,
               
                })
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log('Datos enviados correctamente');
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error al enviar los datos:', error));
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```